# is possible Refresh Gridview from another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to know if is possible refresh a gridview when user update or delete items from another web page.
This is one of our gridviews:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvw_CliEmp_EmpDataNo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" Width="50%"  
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" Font-Size="Small"
        OnRowCommand="gvw_CliEmp_EmpDataNo_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('Clientes_Empleados_DetalleNO.aspx?cliCod= <%#Eval("ClienteCodigo1").ToString() 
                        + "&EmpNom=" + Eval("Empleado1").ToString()
                        + "&EmpCod=" + Eval("IdCliEmp").ToString()
                        + "&EmpNiv=" + Eval("NivelAcceso1").ToString()    
                        %> ','PrintMe','height=500px,width=800px,scrollbars=1');">Editar</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID EMP">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpIdNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdCliEmp") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EMPLEADO">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpNomNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Empleado1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CLIENTE">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_CliCodNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClienteCodigo1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NIVEL">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CliEmp_EmpNivNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NivelAcceso1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdeleteNo" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteNo" 
                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IdCliEmp")%>'>Eliminar
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

If the user clicks edit button appears another web like a pop up but simpler, for this I send values to this new webform:

```
string empNombre, clienteCodigo, empCodigo, empNivel;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        empNombre = Request.QueryString["EmpNom"];
        clienteCodigo = Request.QueryString["cliCod"];
        empCodigo = Request.QueryString["EmpCod"];
        empNivel = Request.QueryString["EmpNiv"];

        lbl_CliEmpDet_CliNomNO.Text = empNombre;
        lbl_CliEmpDet_CliCodNO.Text = clienteCodigo.Replace(" ", "");
        lbl_CliEmpDet_EmpCodNO.Text = empCodigo.Replace(" ", "");
        lbl_CliEmpDet_CliNivNO.Text = empNivel.Replace(" ", "");

        clietnes_Empleados_Cons_DptosxCliente(); //departamentos por cliente

    }
}
```

And bla bla blah... I get data from the first page,
but, when I update or delete records from the second page, I want tha the gridview on first page update without refreshing.

Is this possible? 
I hope anyone can help me please.

PD: I'm not using ajax.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible ! You can make a **session** whenever user update or delete.**Session** value filled with some 'text' and on the Grid View Web form on page load event you can check if session value is 'text' then refresh grid view.

if my answer helpful to you mark as right.

Answer (score 0):

On your GridView page, create a hidden button with an onclick event that does nothing but rebind the GridView.

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRefreshGrid" OnClick="btnRefreshGrid_Click"></button>
</div>

protected void btnRefreshGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView.Rebind();
}
```

Create a JavaScript event on the same page that clicks the button.

```
function refreshGrid(){
    document.getElementById("<%= btnRefreshGrid.ClientID %>").click();
}
```

Then, in your popup, simply call this function in JavaScriot using the parent keyword.

```
//database changes made
parent.refreshGrid();
```